# How to access object in interface method implemented inline in getInstance method of same object

Tags: java, android, interface, inner-classes

I am creating Dialog Fragment Object in Adapter where getInstance() method of that dialog accept interface object which provide method to delete object.
in this case i want to dismiss the dialog once object deleted. but it shows error that the dailog object might not be initialize.

For example I am providing part of getVew() method of adapter:

```
final MyDailog dailog = MyDailog.getInstance((int ObjectValue, position, new MyDailog.OnDelete() {
        @Override
        public void onDeleteItem() {

                 objectList.get(position).setDeleted();
                 dailog.dismiss();                   
        });
```

here position is index of view in getView Method of adapter

@ line "dailog.dismiss();" it gives me error that Error:(182, 45) error: variable dailog might not have been initialized

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the compiler is right: it cannot guarantee that `getInstance` does not call `onDeleteItem` before returning, and in this case `dailog` would not be initialized. The interface `OnDelete` is yours, isn't it? Modify it so that onDeleteItem has the dialog as a parameter.

```
final MyDailog dailog = MyDailog.getInstance((int ObjectValue, position, new MyDailog.OnDelete() {
    @Override
    public void onDeleteItem(MyDailog md) {

             objectList.get(position).setDeleted();
             md.dismiss();                   
    });
```

And of course modify the code calling onDeleteItem to pass the create MyDailog instance.